# Getting multiple values when formula can only handle 1 value

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

What happens when you select multiple months and/or years

[Image 1: What happens when you select multiple months and/or years](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Srz4.png)

The error message

[Image 2: The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2G5f.png)

The measure:

`Actuals less Forecast = 
VAR Max_Date =
    MAX ( 'DateTable'[Date] ) 
VAR Month_End =
    EOMONTH ( TODAY (), 0 )
VAR SupplierProjMinusForecast =
    [Supplier Projected] - [Supplier Forecast]
VAR Year_Row = 
    VALUES ( 'DateTable'[Year] )
VAR Year_Today = 
    YEAR ( TODAY () )
VAR Month_Row =
    VALUES ( 'DateTable'[MonthNumber] )
VAR Month_Today =
    MONTH ( TODAY () )
VAR Date_Compare =

    IF(
        OR(
            Year_Row < Year_Today,
            AND(
                Year_Row = Year_Today,
                Month_Row <= Month_Today
            )
        ),
        SupplierProjMinusForecast,
        IF(
            Max_Date <= Month_End, 
            SupplierProjMinusForecast
        )
    )
Return Date_Compare`

This line seems to be causing all of the problems when multiple months are selected.

`VAR Month_Row =
    VALUES ( 'DateTable'[MonthNumber] )`

Help?

Comment: Can't you use MIN or MAX in stead of VALUES, to enforce the return of a single value?

Comment: It seems like you are calculation a YTD. This can be done with a function: TOTALYTD.